# Register and unregister setInterval() in ES6 angularjs controller class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-ui-router

I am using a controller class as state controller and registered a setInterval() method in constructor to call a service after every 30 secs.

```
export default class abc {

constructor() {
setInterval(() => {
        service class;
      }, 30000 );
}
}
```

Now problem is when state is changed still service call is happening so need to use clearInterval() method but not sure how to use it. 
Since it is not a component so can not use $ondestroy(). Also do not want to use statechange event listener etc. Is there any other way like a destructor  or something like that which can be used to unregister setInterval. I am using angular-ui-router with ES 6 syntax. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$onDestroy` hook is specific to all directive controllers, not only components. It is [triggered on scope `$destroy` event](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/57a972d8999017a17e7d13b27d98bc8416ea9a88/src/ng/compile.js#L2761-L2765).

Since state controllers get their own scopes, for template-based routes this can be done with scope `$destroy` listener:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', () => {
  clearInterval(interval);
});
```

`$onDestroy` is supported in UI Router 1.0 [via component-based routes](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#route-to-component).

Comment: Thank You for the answer .. but i am looking for a solution without using $scope.$on since i am using 'this' in my class.. If there is no way without use of $scope then i will use it... Also i am using older version of ui-router too

Comment: Probably 1 solution i can think of is use wrap this code and respective view under a component and use that component under my main/index page which is rendered when state is invoked.

Comment: The fact that you use `this` doesn't mean that you can't use $scope. Moreover, you should use it whenever necessary - like in this case.

Comment: Btw, there is an extension for UI Router that allows to use components in 0.x. https://github.com/softsimon/ui-router-route-to-components

Comment: Cool.. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Works like charm.